# Running Flet App is invoke the Thread Exception

Tags: python, flet

I'm trying to run the start-up lines of code for Python Flet Library

```
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):
    pass


ft.app(target=main)
```

but during it's running this exception is occurred:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (__connection_loop):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
```

I'm trying to run the program like the Web App and it's work.

Comment: Your code works for me, I suspect this is a package version problem - I've encountered a few before.

What version of Python and Flet are you using? Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: Python - 11.3.1; Flet - 0.6.2. I'm not using a Virtual Env.
Also, I have a point that the following code also runs on my PC (the problem occurred on my laptop)

Comment: Hmm, not 100% sure on the fix, but check the flet and Python versions you are using on your laptop are the same. I'd use a virtual environment. Try an older flet build like flet 0.4 and python 3.7 as part of your debugging

Comment: Thanks! I will try. Mind that's something wrong with laptop settings... But anyway try your option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option for me was to reinstall the Windows. It was something broken at the system so after reinstalling this error is not occurred.